# Discordjs mentions not always resolving

Tags: discord.js

I am trying to implement a list of users inside a Discord Embed. The list contains a mention for each user and I have been partially successful in accomplishing that. However, it appears that my bot cannot mention everyone, some of the mentions aren't being resolved, and I wonder why is that so. Is it related to the cache? Is there a way to fetch the mentions like fetching users that aren't cached by the bot?

[An image of the bot output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VMjYQ.png)

```
    leastActiveMembers.forEach((member, index) => {
        let mention =  `<@${member.user.id}>`;

        let lastActive = "";

        if (member.user.activity) {
            lastActive = new Date(member.user.activity.latestActivityTimestamp).toLocaleString("en-GB"); 
        } else {
            lastActive = "Never";
        }

        lastActive = lastActive.padEnd(20, " ");

        leaderBoardRepresentation += `\`${lastActive} ⌛ \`${mention}\n`;
    });

    const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('#DAA520')
        .setTitle(" Activity Board                 ")
        .setDescription(leaderBoardRepresentation)
        .setThumbnail('https://i.imgur.com/v5RR3ro.png')
        .setFooter({ text: footer, iconURL: "" })
```

I am using discordjs v13.

Comment: This is just how Discord generally works, you cant display users names as mentions if they have never been in the server

Comment: As stated above, this is down to Discord and there is nothing you can do regarding it. It relies solely on the Discord cache.

Comment: The problems is, I am retrieving the whole members list with the `guild.members.fetch()` call, but discord responds with a very ancient result from the cache. There aren't members that haven't been to my server, but there are members that have been there and aren't present anymore. I suppose since these user id's aren't anymore in my server, I cannot use mentions.

Comment: I used @NotTrixxie comment and made it into an answer. If it helped, please mark it as the best answer to close the thread.

Answer (score 1):

As [@NotTrixxie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6555670/nottrixxie) said, this is Discord's built-in code which we cannot modify. If a user has no relation to the bot (not in the server), it will display it. If you want the username to show, you can display the username instead of mentioning which will work. See below for an example of this:

```js
leastActiveMembers.forEach((member, index) => {
    const mention = member.user.username;

    let lastActive = '';

    if (member.user.activity) {
        lastActive = new Date(member.user.activity.latestActivityTimestamp).toLocaleString('en-GB');
    } else {
        lastActive = 'Never';
    }

    lastActive = lastActive.padEnd(20, ' ');

    leaderBoardRepresentation += `\`${lastActive} ⌛ \`${mention}\n`;
});

const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('#DAA520')
    .setTitle(' Activity Board                 ')
    .setDescription(leaderBoardRepresentation)
    .setThumbnail('https://i.imgur.com/v5RR3ro.png')
    .setFooter({
        text: footer,
    })
```

**Hoped this helped!**

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Unfortunately, it's not what I asked for. I am going to see if there exists a sure way to verify if an user is in the server and then I should be able to mention them.

Comment: @violetflare Can you upvote it?